# Why is Measurement Device Independent (MDI) Quantum Key Distribution (QKD) truly MDI?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-computer

I am having a hard time understanding why MDI-QKD is truly measurement device independent.
My current vision is that Charlie (the one who performs the Bell state measurements) is simply sampling the qubits Alice and Bob sent: the ones for which the measurement does not fail should have certain correlations.

But why is this schema imune against all detector side channels?

Comment: This might be of interest also for the [quantum computing Stack Exchange](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Can I repost it there?

Comment: Sure, just say that you reposted it and put a link to this one.

Comment: I'd suggest a search on [crypto.se].